# Replacing a for loop with a while loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have written a function that estimates the inverse of `e` and loops through values of `n` until the approximated value is within a given `tolerance` of the actual value.

Currently I use this code:

```
function [approx, n] = calc_e(tolerance)

for n = 1:inf
    approx = ((1-1/n)^n);
    diff = (1/exp(1)) - approx;
    if diff < tolerance, break; end
end
end
```

This works fine however I have been told that it could be more efficient by using a `while` loop but I can't work out how to do it in that way.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: I do not think that it would make any difference in matlab

Comment: furthermore, the name of the func is missleading, you are approximating `1/e`, not `e` (which would require (1+1/n)^n

Comment: You really should avoid using built-in functions names like [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) as variable names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
function [approx, n] = calc_e(tolerance)
n = 1;
while (1/exp(1)) - ((1-1/n)^n) >= tolerance
   n = n + 1;
end
end
```

Comment: you forgot about n ... initializing, incrementing

Comment: actually you can stil have a one-liner, you can put expression for diff inside while condition and increment in the body